# Partially use the -y argument when installing things in Debian in one line

Tags: debian, apt, arguments

I have a long apt-get install sequence and for most software packages I need the `-y` argument.

I could do the following in two lines:

```
apt-get upgrade unattended-upgrades sshguard curl wget git ansible zip unzip tree mc lamp-server^ -y
apt-get upgrade python-certbot-apache
```

But is there a way to do all in one line like?

```
apt upgrade unattended-upgrades sshguard curl wget git -y ansible zip unzip tree mc -y lamp-server^ python-certbot-apache
```

<sub>Note the two `-y` arguments inside the sequence.</sub>

I can't test right now.

Comment: Does it really work like that? It seems to me that the `-y` option turns it on globally for the command?

Comment: Could you explain why you want `-y` for some packages and not for others? What’s different about the two sets of packages? Also, shouldn’t it be `apt install` rather than `upgrade`?

Comment: @StephenKitt yes I usually use `upgrade` (just use install as a legacy assuming not all know the `upgrade`). Anyway, I assumed some packages doesn't need `-y` especially for `certbot` because our beloved user:terdon once told that such long packages name (as of certbot and PPAs) can frequently change and therefore I should use `-y` on them. Thoughts?

Comment: @StephenKitt sorry according to `terdon` I **shouldn't** use `-y` on them as they might frequently change (unlike package names like `tree`, `zip`, `ansible` and so forth).

Comment: I read that from your first comment, but I don’t see the connection. `apt install python-certbot-apache` and `apt install -y python-certbot-apache` will both fail in the same way if `python-certbot-apache` is no longer available. Also, you won’t see package name changes in a stable release (well, apart from kernel packages, but you should use the kernel meta-packages anyway).

Comment: Hmm, so I wonder why terdon told me at least twice to get the `-y` out of there (100% it had to with `certbot`). I'll try to show him this conversation. Thank you.

Comment: Also, this proves even more why I (and anyone else in a similar state) need Ansible.

Comment: @JohnDoea I don't know what conversation you're referring to but I probably told you not to use `-y` so you could actually see the prompts and be warned before replacing packages with different ones. The `-y` won't protect you from changed names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apt install -y unattended-upgrades sshguard curl wget git ansible zip unzip tree mc lamp-server^ && apt install python-certbot-apache
```